# Xcode 11 Beta 5 - Loading a plug-in failed

Tags: xcode, beta

Opening a SwiftUI "Hello World" unaltered project in Xcode 11 beta 5 running on Catalina beta 4 produces a "Loading a plug-in failed" dialog warning.

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this or know how to solve it? I deleted Xcode, redownloaded it, reinstalled it and I'm still getting the same error.

No idea how to fix other than deleting the offending module, but that can't be right.

Error details:
Details

```
Loading a plug-in failed.
Domain: DVTPlugInErrorDomain
Code: 2
Failure Reason: The plug-in “com.apple.dt.UVKit” at path “/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework” could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged.
Recovery Suggestion: The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled.
User Info: {
    DVTPlugInDYLDErrorMessageErrorKey = "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit, 0): Symbol not found: _$s2IDs12IdentifiablePTl\n  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit\n  Expected in: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib\n in /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit";
    DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey = "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit";
    DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey = "com.apple.dt.UVKit";
    NSFilePath = "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework";
}
--
The bundle “UVKit” couldn’t be loaded.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 3588
Failure Reason: The bundle couldn’t be loaded.
Recovery Suggestion: Try reinstalling the bundle.
User Info: {
    NSBundlePath = "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework";
    NSDebugDescription = "dlopen(/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit, 265): Symbol not found: _$s2IDs12IdentifiablePTl\n  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit\n  Expected in: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib\n in /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit";
    NSFilePath = "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit";
}
--
```

Comment: The notes basically say only the loss of canvas previews. Catalina 5 is not available yet. I was asking if anyone else has experienced it and indicated that I solved it by deleting a module. again, asking if anyone else has experienced it so that I know its not related to my environment.

Comment: That statement by Apple is very vague, it's not telling me much. Thanks for your opinion, ask is the same.

Comment: Where does it say "Its not supported" that's different from "know issues". I read the list of known issues and its not listed. So I can't ask the question? Wow

Comment: You can ask it, sure (though the _way_ to ask it was to specify what system you're running on, as well as the Xcode beta). I'm just suggesting that the only way to know if there's a real problem here is to try it when they are both at beta 5. There is certainly no such problem with Xcode beta 5 on Mojave, so there is a strong likelihood that the impedance mismatch is reponsible.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta and XCode 11.0 Beta 5. Any help to reinstall the plugin or other workaround will be appreciated!

Comment: After update to Catelina beta 5 the error wen't away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get my SwiftUI project running on Catalina beta 4 with Xcode beta 5. I too got the warning mentioned by OP.

And as mentioned in comments, the only negative impact I've seen is being unable to use the preview canvas. Other than that, everything else in my project is running well. Just using the simulator more ;)

Comment: Thank you Scott, that's the information I needed to confirm it wasn't isolated to my environment, saving me the work of rebuilding my laptop!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is gone on Catalina build 19A558d when installing Xcode 11 GM Seed (build 11A419c, released September 10, 2019)

Answer (score 0):

this will get rid of the error message but will not bring canvas back.

based on:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120614

Please go to: `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework` and delete all the shortcut files in all folders of `UVKit.framework` (Be sure DONOT delete orginal files).

Comment: This remove the popup message but SwiftUI preview canvas will still be broken